# How to detect if all the rows of a matrix are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a non-square matrix with integer entries, how can you detect if all the rows are orthogonal? One option is just to compute the inner product for every pair of rows but is there a better way?

My matrix has fewer rows than columns and the rows are not unit vectors.

Comment: You can try taking the transpose, then try finding the determinant of the matrix formed with the transpose of the rows.

Comment: The proof of the pudding is the multiplying,

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Check the off-diagonals of $A*A^T$ are $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rows of the matrix are orthogonal iff $AA^T$ is diagonal.

**Note:** Since $AA^T$ is symmetric, computing $AA^T$ only involves computing the upper triangular part and the diagonal, the lower triangular part of $AA^T$ is a reflection across the diagonal of the upper triangular part. Even with this simplification, computing $AA^T$ is actually more work than checking that each row is orthogonal to each other row because computing $AA^T$ also computes the diagonal elements, which are irrelevant to checking the orthogonality of the rows.

Answer (score 2):

If there are $n$ rows, then $AA^T$ is $n\times n$. Unless you know something special about how $A$ was formed in the first place that might give you more information, then there is nothing quicker than checking the upper off-diagonal entries of $AA^T$. They all need to be zero. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ entries to check, corresponding to each pair of two distinct rows (which as you have noted is one way to check).